# FastCGI - How do I tell if it is properly running on my NGINX web server?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Is there a command I can run? How do I know it is caching my wordpress site?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a curl request to your site and take a look at the `X-FastCGI-Cache` header. `HIT` indicates the response was served from cache.

`curl -I http://www.your-domain.com`